# What framework and compiler directive to use for portable class libary in ASP.NET5?

Tags: portable-class-library, asp.net-core, compiler-directives

What framework and compiler directive to use for portable class library in ASP.NET5?

For framwwork, that **"pcl"** ?

```
"pcl": {
    "frameworkAssemblies": {
        // ...
    },
    "dependencies": {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And as compiler directive, is that **"PORTABLE"** ?

```
#if PORTABLE
//
#else
//
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there is no support for PCL.

Comment: Is this by design (please share a link) or is it a bug/missing feature?